# dataTables not populating in struts2 hibernate

Tags: datatables, struts2-jquery

I have a jquery datable that should get loaded with a table data. I am using struts2 Hibernate.

JSP Page:

```js
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".jqueryDataTable").dataTable({
                    "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
                    "bProcessing" : false,
                    "bServerSide" : false,
                    "sAjaxSource" : "getProductPropData",
                    "bJQueryUI" : true,
                    "aoColumns" : [
                { "mData": "densityId" },
                { "mData": "densityDescription" }
            ]
        } ); 
    } );
    </script>
```

struts.xml

```xml
<package name="json" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
  <action name="getProductPropData" class="com.test.action.PropertyListDataAction">
     <result type="json">
        <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
        <param name="noCache">true</param>
     </result>
  </action>
</package>
```

Action Class:

```java
public String execute() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SessionFactory sf = (SessionFactory) ctx.getAttribute("SessionFactory");
        ProductPropertyDAO pdao = new ProductPropertyDAOImpl(sf);
        List<DensityGroup> dg = pdao.getProductPropListData("Density");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        jsonData = gson.toJson(dg);
        System.out.println("dg:"+dg);
        return "success";
        }
```

I am getting response from the database in json format but my datatable is not getting populated.

[image: Console Output[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh1Nj.png)

JSON output:

```
{"jsonData":"[{\"densityId\":15,\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":11,\"densityDescription\":\"Mcvr\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":14,\"densityDescription\":\"test\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":16,\"densityDescription\":\"Chitti\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":12,\"densityDescription\":\"MCVR\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":13,\"densityDescription\":\"4\\\" DIA\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":14,\"densityDescription\":\"test\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":15,\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":21,\"densityDescription\":\"1 1\/4\\\" DIA\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":22,\"densityDescription\":\"3\/4\\\" DIA\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":37,\"densityDescription\":\"25\\\"DIA\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":24,\"densityDescription\":\"8\\\" DIA\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":25,\"densityDescription\":\"1 1\/8\\\" DIA\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":28,\"densityDescription\":\"6\\\"\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":29,\"densityDescription\":\"1\/2\\\" DIA\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":30,\"densityDescription\":\"EXHAUST STEAM\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":19,\"densityDescription\":\"1 1\/2\\\" DIA\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":44,\"densityDescription\":\"EXHAUSTCLADDING\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":1,\"densityDescription\":\"16 KG\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":11,\"densityDescription\":\"Mcvr\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":2,\"densityDescription\":\"20 KG\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":3,\"densityDescription\":\"24 KG\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":5,\"densityDescription\":\"48 KG\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":6,\"densityDescription\":\"64 KG\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":7,\"densityDescription\":\"96 KG\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":8,\"densityDescription\":\"100 KG\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":9,\"densityDescription\":\"128 KG \",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":10,\"densityDescription\":\"120 KG \",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":18,\"densityDescription\":\"144KG\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":23,\"densityDescription\":\"5\\\" DIA\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":26,\"densityDescription\":\"4\\\"\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":27,\"densityDescription\":\"125 KG\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":34,\"densityDescription\":\"10\\\" DIA\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":32,\"densityDescription\":\"18\\\" \",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":33,\"densityDescription\":\"12\\\" DIA\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":35,\"densityDescription\":\"14\\\" DIA\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":36,\"densityDescription\":\"5\/8\\\" DIA\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":38,\"densityDescription\":\"(1\/2 x 24 SWG)\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":39,\"densityDescription\":\"8\\\" FLANGE\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":40,\"densityDescription\":\"6\\\" FLANGE\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":41,\"densityDescription\":\"3\\\" FLANGE\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":42,\"densityDescription\":\"25 MM DIA\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":43,\"densityDescription\":\"150 KG\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":46,\"densityDescription\":\"INSULATION WORK\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":47,\"densityDescription\":\"18\\\" DIA\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":16,\"densityDescription\":\"Chitti\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":45,\"densityDescription\":\"1 3\/8 DIA\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":56,\"densityDescription\":\"18 KG\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":55,\"densityDescription\":\"40 KG\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":48,\"densityDescription\":\"85 KG\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":49,\"densityDescription\":\"2\\\"\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":50,\"densityDescription\":\"12 KG\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":53,\"densityDescription\":\"FLANGES\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":51,\"densityDescription\":\"2 1\/2\\\" DIA\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":52,\"densityDescription\":\"INSULATION \",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":54,\"densityDescription\":\"VALVES\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":57,\"densityDescription\":\"CLASS O\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":58,\"densityDescription\":\"140 KG\",\"validationAware\":{}},{\"densityId\":59,\"densityDescription\":\"30 KG\",\"validationAware\":{}}]"}
```

Comment: go to your network tab and see what the json coming back looks like.  There are specific properties that need to be there per the datatable docs.  Also, bServerSide should be true.

Comment: I have attached an image here with what is coming in network tab. I am getting a JSON back but not sure whether the format of the JSON is correct

see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh1Nj.png

Comment: This json is not correct for DataTables.  Here is the doc for what the json needs to look like coming back. http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Hi Paul, How do I bring my JSON to the desired format. Any insights please ? I am trying options of "stringify"

Comment: @MittintiRamanaMurthy, your JSON is completely screwed up.  It only validates because of the escaped quotes, basically it is just a long string. Even if you sanitize the string you end up with something that is not JSON. You lack :, " and more. You have entitites such as `140 KG ","`

Comment: Hi David, What I should I do make my JSON correct.

Comment: This is still a problem, i m unable to figure out how to reform my json so that the dataTable populates the data. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

By default datatables looks for the 'data' element in the json.
It can't find it, therefore it's 'undefined'. DataTables provides a way to specify the element to use. Comparing your json with that on the documentation link below you should be able to specify ajax.dataSrc = "jsonData" or change "jsonData" to "data" in your data object.
I would recommend switching to the new naming convention for the datatable options if possible, it's more clear and the documentation is tailored towards it. If you can't use the new naming scheme changing your json object is probably the best option.

Documentation:
https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have changed the name to 'data' I am getting the following errors.

1) Getting two pop-up messages one after other

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkZHO.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VytVt.png

2) Seeing 3,992 entries in the table, my JSON is not that lengthy.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGY6f.png

3) If I input a string in search bar, I see it is filtering.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ3U3.png

** Follow the links to see the screenshots **

Comment: There are additional issues with your data. Your datatable configuration specifies two names to look for, densityId and densityDescription, these MUST be present the data for each row. Your first row doesn't contain a densityDescription node causing the datatables.net/tn/4 error. The other errors are for the same issue, but different node name. Make sure each row contains all fields referenced in the datatable config. After that you should start seeing data in your table.